# Apache2.4: How to add other ports on CentOS7?

Tags: apache-http-server

I don't know why I can't connect from other ports.

My Apache Server, based on CentOS7, It does not open except a few ports(e.g. 17490 27490 27480, 28483 and ...)

So, I checked and tested ports.
I checked firewall, vhost, netstat and iperf simple test.

Run iperf -s -p port_number, port_number is open and success connecting client to server!

Why do not add port in apache?

OS: CentOS7

Apache: 2.4

Comment: firewall? Selinux?

Comment: @davidgo firewall-cmd --list-port return i-want-port and disable selinux but same error. I have tried some tests (including reinstallation) and it seems that virtualhost is not being applied. The link is my virtualhost configuration.
https://gist.github.com/bluems/f7f026fd750ff70260dd59179c1ad28c

phpinfo() > apache2handler is show Virtual Server - yes

Comment: @davidgo Sorry, permissive is same error and disable selinux is no error! But I should use selinux. I need a lot of selinux study. Look at the logs and add them back.